# Control axis tick number in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use this code to create over one hundred graphs, each one being a unique graph and plotting different points. However, I need their general layouts to look the same.

When using the .ticks() function D3 seems to completely ignore whatever value I input. Every one of my graphs always comes out with a different number of ticks but I can't find a way to fix it.  Is there a way to force D3 to accept my value?

This is the relevant code:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()  
  .orient("bottom")
  .scale(x)
  .ticks(10)
  .tickFormat(d3.format("d"))
  .tickSize(1);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(10)
  .tickSize(1);

var yAxixObject = graph.append("g")
  .call(yAxis)
  .attr("transform", "translate("+ margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var xAxisObject = graph.append("g")
  .call(xAxis)
  .attr("transform", "translate("+ margin.left + "," + (height + margin.top) + ")");
```

Comment: .tickValues([1,2,3,...]) takes precedence over the tick arguments set by axis.ticks...according to the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues). You would use the actual values you want displayed, if that is feasible.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes I looked into that already unfortunately that won't work because each of my graphs use different values.

Comment: If you know the range of each graph, you could still come up with a uniform number of tick points to pass in, no?

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Although now that you mention it, I'm wondering if I can create the appropriate values using the max and min functions and input variables into .tickValues()... I will try this next time I get the chance. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, we just cross-posted...it was my thought in the last comment.

Comment: Yes, the ticks function prefers to have round numbers for the tick values as being more important than creating the exact number of ticks you requested.  If you want a different behaviour, you're going to have to implement your own function for figuring out the ticks.  If you get something working, come back and post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From FernOfTheAndes' suggestion I ended up using the .tickValues() function. I just added a loop to create an array to input into .tickValues(). Now regardless of how different all the data is, my graphs all still have 10 ticks.

This is all the relevant code for my y axis, that is dispersed throughout my project:

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickSize(1);

...

var ticksNum = 10;
var yAxisTicks = [];
var yDomain = [d3.min(data, function(d){return d.Level;}), d3.max(data, function(d){return d.Level;})];
y.domain(yDomain);

...

for (var i = 0; i < ticks; i++ ){
          yAxisTicks.push((yDomain[1] - yDomain[0]) / (ticks - 1)* i + yDomain[0]);
    }

yAxis.tickValues(yAxisTicks);

...

var yAxixObject = graph.append("g")
  .call(yAxis)
  .attr("transform", "translate("+ margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Comment: minor improvement: you can use d3.extent instead of calling d3.min and d3.max separately when you calculate yDomain.